# Build error using golang race detector

Tags: go, build

My software compiles and runs fine but when I add the -race option to check for race conditions it does not build:

```
GOROOT=C:\Go

GOPATH=<deleted>;D:\Golang

C:\Go\bin\go.exe build -race -o C:\Users\Andrewp\AppData\Local\Temp\___1Race_Detector.exe -gcflags "-N -l" -a <deleted>

# runtime/cgo

gcc_libinit_windows.c: In function 'x_cgo_sys_thread_create':
gcc_libinit_windows.c:56:12: error: implicit declaration of function '_beginthread' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  thandle = _beginthread(func, 0, arg);
            ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors

Compilation finished with exit code 2
```

Note that it worked previously but I have since upgraded to go version go1.9.2 windows/amd64 (though I don't think that is related).  Also have MSYS installed.

Also I am building with GoLand (under Windows 10) but I get the same problem when I build from the command line.

Does anyone have info on how the Go compiler works esp. when using race detector or cgo, so I can track down the cause of this?

Extra info:
I can build fine from the terminal using:

> go build -race

It seems that the problem is caused by the -a option that GoLand added to the command line since this almost identical command line fails:

> go build -race -a .

But this is OK:

> go build -a .

Comment: I get the same error if I try to use cgo.

Comment: I upgraded to go version go1.10.3 with the same results although in that case the command line that GoLand provides is slightly different:
go build -race -o ___Race_Detector.exe -gcflags "all=-N -l" <dir>

Comment: Can you provide code which reproduces the issue?

Comment: On a different system (without MSYS installed) I get a different error:
exec: "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%

Comment: I think the shown example is also using CGO, maybe you could try without it?  just a wild guess.

Comment: @Momer it happens with any project at all. I could include the "hello world" project if you like

Comment: @Daniel - no it happens with any project - ie does not have to use CGO.  But it also happens with any project that uses CGO even if I don't use the race detector.  To summarize it happens with (1) Any project when I use `go build -race -a`,
(2) Any project that uses CGO even without any special options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late update:  I got it to build (much later) by upgrading the version of GCC I had installed.

Answer (score 2):

Details are in this [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27089).
A workaround is usually to set `-vet=off`

Comment: How to set "-vet=off" ?

Comment: Reference of go test -vet is here: https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Test_packages