# cgo: C compiler "gcc" not found: exec: "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%

Tags: go, testing

I'm playing with some Go code and when I try to test something with

```
go test -race .
```

I get this:

```
cgo: C compiler "gcc" not found: exec: "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%
```

but this:

```
go test .
```

make all tests pass with flying colours.

My Go version is 1.19, os is windows 10 I also can read this message and it says that I'm missing gcc but why on the other hand this runs fine?

```
go run -race .
```

Comment: Try `go test -race -vet=off .` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51738607/11810946) for more info).

Answer (score 0):

For Windows it is best to use "scoop" to install it

The steps as are as follows

1. Install "scoop" using the latest instructions on its website: https://scoop.sh/

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
irm get.scoop.sh | iex
```

2.Install Mingw

```
scoop install mingw
```

3. Check if installed successfully

```
gcc -v
```

4. Restart your VS Code to use it from the terminal

Answer (score -2):

Just do `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Comment: "os is windows 10"

Comment: This would work on Ubuntu, not windows